# Java regex finds only last match when I want all

Tags: java, regex

I have this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(MyFunc[(](?s).*[)];).*", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

I want to match all the occurances of MyFunc(ANYTHING); .

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The above only prints only the last match in text

```
Binding(CTRL+O, MyFunc("test1\ndkjs");  ParameterizedCommand(C
MyFunc("test2"); dskj MyFunc("test3\n"); kdjskfjskjfksjf
```

**Desired output:**

```
MyFunc("test1\ndkjs");
MyFunc("test2");
MyFunc("test3\n");
```

Comment: Have you encountered the difference between greedy and non-greedy quantifiers?

Comment: Yes. I've encountered once in the past. But in my case, don't I need a greedy quantifier? If not then I must be missing something. I was never good with regexes.

Comment: I don't need a solution ready to go. A simple guide of what to do would suffice. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok from the answers I understand my error. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to capture all the "calls" to `MyFunc` then the regex you need is

```
(MyFunc[(](?s).*?[)];)
```

See the [live demo at Regexr](http://regexr.com?378iq)

Also consider avoiding the dot-stars and get the part inside the parentheses with non-right-parens, like so:

```
 (MyFunc[(][^)]*[)];)
```

[Live demo for this alternative](http://regexr.com?378it)

Also note that the regxr demos linked to above have the dot-all and global and multiline flags set; so you can match things like

```
MyFunc(
   xyz
   );
```

You can easily add these flags to your regex when put into your code.  Note there is no need for the inner `(?s)` if you go with `[^)]*`

[Third and last live demo, showing line breaks within call](http://regexr.com?378j0)

Answer (score 2):

Try the exact same code with this regex:

```
(MyFunc\\(.*?\\);)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you have a \n in your input. It will produce a new line in the output.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm going to select Ray's answer because of the live demo (It was a close call :P). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find

```
MyFunc("test1\ndkjs");
MyFunc("test2");
MyFunc("test3\n");
```

then just you don't need `.*` at start or end of your regex. Just create regex that will match `MyFunc(`, zero or more characters that are not `)` and `);` at the end.

Something like `MyFunc\\([^)]*\\);`